# joining many tables in 1 query resulting in duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called 'games'.

A game can have multiple tags and multiple authors. Each tag or author can belong to multiple games.

I want to keep track of each individual tag and each individual author with separate tables, so I have the following tables and their columns:

games: id, ...
game_tags: id, name
game_tags_map: id, game_id, tag_id
game_authors: id, name
game_authors_map: id, game_id, author_id

If I want to get a game record with all its tags I execute the following query:

```
SELECT g.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(gt.name) as tag_names, GROUP_CONCAT(gt.id) as tag_ids
FROM games g    
INNER JOIN game_tags_map gtm ON g.id = gtm.game_id
INNER JOIN game_tags gt ON gtm.tag_id = gt.id    
WHERE g.id = 1
GROUP BY g.id
```

And I get:

```
id ... category_names    category_ids
1  ... 3D,2 Player       2,1
```

Exactly as I want it. However, what do I execute in order to get author_names and author_ids as well?
I try:

```
SELECT g.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(gt.name) as tag_names, GROUP_CONCAT(gt.id) as tag_ids,
GROUP_CONCAT(ga.name) as author_names, GROUP_CONCAT(ga.id) as author_ids
FROM games g    
INNER JOIN game_tags_map gtm ON g.id = gtm.game_id
INNER JOIN game_tags gt ON gtm.tag_id = gt.id
INNER JOIN game_authors_map gam ON g.id = gam.game_id
INNER JOIN game_authors ga ON gam.author_id = ga.id    
WHERE g.id = 1
GROUP BY g.id
```

But I get:

```
id ... category_names           category_ids      author_names          author_ids
1  ... 3D,2 Player,3D,2 Player  2,1,2,1           Tom,Dave,Tom,Dave       1,2,1,2
```

In other words, everything doubles.
Also I notice it takes almost 10 times longer than I expected it to take. The first query took 0.001s, the second one took 0.008s.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Will `group_concat(distinct ...)` fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to use distinct on GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT
  g.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gt.name) as tag_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gt.id) as tag_ids,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ga.name) as author_names,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ga.id) as author_ids
FROM ....
```

another solution is to use GROUP_CONCAT in subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT
  g.id,
  tag_names,
  author_names,
  ...
FROM
  games g INNER JOIN (SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS tag_names
                      FROM ...
                      GROUP BY id) t
  ON g.id=t.id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS author_names
              FROM ...
              GROUP BY id) a
  ON g.id = a.id
```

Comment: The second solution makes much more sense to me, however I've just done a bit of testing and found it takes significantly longer to execute... I might just make it simpler by removing the mapping tables and repeating the author name / tag name for each record in the respective tables.